# What is the meaning of public key parameter in the X.509 certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, rsa, x.509

While I am checking the fields of X.509 I've noticed there is field called public key parameter and its value is 05, what is the use of this field? I have searched and did not find a clear answer for that.

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays the most important use of field "key parameters" is within ECDSA certificate; the field holds an elliptic curve per [RFC 5480 section 2.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt).

Still, as of 2017, most people use RSA certificates; for these [RFC 4055 section 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4055.txt) says "the parameters field MUST contain NULL" (except the fringe RSASSA-PSS or RSAES-OAEP). Bytes `05 00` simply mean NULL in DER (and CER and BER).